# K-1 visa for nearly expiring Venezuelan passport

Tags: k1-visa

My fiance and I are planning on applying for a K-1 visa within the next few weeks. I am a US citizen and I have a US passport valid for a few more years. She, however, has a "prorroga" - an extension to her already expired Venezuelan passport. If the visa process takes around a year then it's likely that when the interview happens her extension will not be valid for 6 more months. Because of the situation in Venezuela, obtaining a new passport at this time is an extremely expensive and lengthy process. Does the US rule of adding 5 years to expired Venezuelan passports still apply for the K-1 visa process?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the US's [5-year extension of validity for Venezuelan passports](https://2017-2021.state.gov/the-united-states-supports-extension-of-validity-for-venezuelan-passports/index.html) still applies. (See for example [this FAQ for Diversity Visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DV-Resources/Passport-Entry-FAQ.pdf) and [this CBP answer](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1411?language=en_US).) The 5 years starts from the end of the extension provided by the "prórroga". In any case, Venezuela is part of the [6-month club](https://fam.state.gov/FAM/09FAM/09FAM040309.html#M403_9_3_B_2) so Venezuelan passports do not normally need to be valid for 6 months at the time of nonimmigrant entry.